# Extracting Columns and Rows from a file

Tags: grep, bioinformatics

I have a list of some 164 SNPs that I need to match to a very large .txt file from a database and extract some columns and rows matching those SNPs from that text file and print it into a new text file.

Comment: Sample input & output?

Comment: so the input file is like this I have some Rs Ids of a SNP that I need to search in a data base file. the input file is like this. 
rs10093110
rs6993696
rs28416651
rs12216772


where as the database file has multiple columns with one column named as SNP IDs thats contains the above mentioned ids I need to match my SNP ids with that SNP IDs column and extract relevant information. I managed to extract using grep -f mylist.txt databaselist.txt | cut -f 1,2,3 > output.txt. but the output file contains the partial matched rs ids too. do you have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details about the formatting of your data would be helpful.  With no details at all, we'll have to make some assumptions:

- the SNPs are listed one per line in some file
- your data rows are whitespace-delimited
- an SNP appearing anywhere in the row qualifies as a match on that row
- we want columns 1, 2, and 3 from each matching row

In that case, try this:

`grep -f list_of_SNPs.txt  very_large.txt | cut -f 1,2,3 > new_file.txt`

Comment: hey thank you so much for your help. I would like to report an issue. when I tried to search SNPs using a text file it somehow didn't work. but when I search using SNPs one by one in that file using 

grep -F 'rs124565'  very_large.txt | cut -f 1,2,3 > new_file.txt it worked.

I don't know why but somehow -f command isn't working. can you please assist me to debug this issue? I have tried allot of stuff but couldn't figure out  the issue.

Comment: Your file is badly formatted.  A common problem is that it was created on Windows and contains carriage returns.  Try `cat -tv snp.txt` ... does each line end in `^M`?  If so, you need to copy/paste into a new file, or run `dos2unix snp.txt`

Comment: Hello I have one more issue while using this command I managed to extract the columns but the it extracted partial matched rs IDs too. I need an exact matched rs ids. do you have any solution to that as well?

Comment: yes, in SNPs.txt, include the field separator at the start and end of each line.  To match exactly `abc` in comma-delimited file, your pattern would be `,abc,`.  If SNP is first field, use `^` instead to match beginning-of-line, as in `^abc,`